# Approach need for the development of web method testing tool

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

We have a Web API project now I have to create a tool where I can test the methods of the Web API. I need to create a tool where if I give the request I need to get the XML response in UI. What approach should I follow?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SwaggerUI` as documentation and request testing tool. More information about Swagger can be found at their [official site](https://swagger.io/).

There are some helpful guides how to configure `SwaggerUI` for your application:
  1. ASP.NET MVC Web API 2: https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/how-to-use-swagger-in-web-api
  2. ASP.NET Core Web API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle

Answer (score 0):

Use Accept header while sending the request as "application/json" or "application/xml". Add xml formatting to list of formatters if not already done.

Read more on content negotiation here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by saying that you need to get the XML response in UI. If you need to test something manually and actually see the returned response, then Swagger is the most popular and easy-to-use option I would suggest you.

However, if you need to write automated tests, I would highly recommend you to try the [MyTested ASP.Net](https://mytestedasp.net/) framework. I personally use it in every web project that I do. It is pretty easy to start writing all kind of tests, it has a lot of functionalities within and can be configured for almost every case. The author is a very kind person and a friend of mine that dedicates most of its time on that project and can always relate to your problems (if such exist) and needs to build a better product.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to perform integration tests against your APIs, you can use Postman: [Postman](https://www.postman.com/)